# how to write a daemon to take a recent snapshot of an CSV file and store it locally

Tags: python, csv, daemon

I working on a problem, to copy a CSV file which is getting updated every n second to another CSV file.
This process of copying should take a recent snapshot and should work seamlessly in the background as a daemon.

I have a no clue where to start. Any suggestions?

currently, I'm using pandas to read the CSV file

result = pandas.read_csv(r'\test.csv')

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: windows with remote connection on centOS

Comment: Haven't tried myself but a quick search came up with ["systemd" as a good way of running scripts periodically on CentOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198450). Here's a [link specifically for on-file change](https://superuser.com/a/1276457), if that's more of what you're looking for. And some [lower-level protocol](https://superuser.com/a/363513) if you prefer. So long as you're simply a copying the file, then you should be able to just use [the shutil module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) to do so (no need for pandas).

Comment: thanks, @ReidBallard. This works!